# Switching between child forms wrapped with redux form and with the same identifier also destroys parent form values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-form

So we have a form which includes a dropdown from which a user selects one of several options.
Then we fetch the value of the selected option from the store using formValueSelector and display one of several forms which is determined by the selected value.
Everything works fine until the user decides to switch options and by extension, child forms.
The entire form state is destroyed, and you have to start again.

We can't use `destroyOnUnmount: false because it would keep child form values even after the child form is unmounted.

```js
//Parent Form
class ParentForm extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    truckType: PropTypes.string
  }

  render() {
    const { truckType } = this.props;
    
    const displayTypeForms = () => {
      switch(truckType) {
        case 'Child One':
          return <ChildForm1 />;
        case 'Child Two':
          return <ChildForm2 />;
        default:
          return <View />;
      }
    };

    return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
        <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
          <KeyboardAvoidingView>
            <View>
              <Field
                name="exampleName"
                component={Picker}
              />
              
              {displayTypeForms()}
              
            </View>
          </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        </ScrollView>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  let selector = formValueSelector('mobilePostForm');
  const truckType = selector(state, 'truckType');
  return {
    truckType,
  };
};

export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps),
  reduxForm({
    form: 'mobilePostForm',
  })
)(ParentForm);
```

```js
// Example of Child Form
class ChildForm1 extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View></View>
    );
  }
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'mobilePostForm',
})(ChildForm1);
```

Comment: why you are using same name for different forms? It seems should be unique, isnt it?

Comment: They are child forms, aka, contribute to the form state (and data) of their parent. Using child forms with different form names would load a completely new form in the reducer and destroy the parent form (I think).

Comment: Maybe you can use [FormSection](https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/docs/api/formsection.md/) as subform to not loose state?

Comment: Still gets destroyed when form unmounts.